# sql query implement two count in one

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot

```
SELECT (select count(u.ag_code) 
from table1 as u inner join table2 as tc 
on u.industry_id=tc.tempcatid 
where u.ag_code!=0) as agnt,
    (select count(u.ag_code) 
     from table1 as u inner join table2 as tc 
     on u.industry_id=tc.tempcatid where u.ag_code=0),as dircus,
tc.catename from table1 as u inner join table2 as tc 
where u.industry_id=tc.tempcatid 
group by tc.tempcatid
```

this query have error
i need two count and category name in one query
this is the condition for count

1. ag_code!=0
2. ag_code=0

in table1 have column ag_code  (this have 0 and nonzero value)

my result need like this

```
Full Texts
agent   customer    catename
11  3   Real Estate
15  1   Automobile
3   0   Medical
34  77  Business
1   45  Travel & Hotels
11  3   Construction & Engineering
```

Comment: Try this http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/750578-how-use-two-count-single-query

Comment: What is the question? What results are you getting with the query you posted?

Comment: I really tried to focus on what exactly your query is doing, but I really couldn't grasp it. You'll need to describe in a little more detail what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tc.catename,
       count(case when u.ag_code!=0 then 1 end) agnt,
       count(case when u.ag_code =0 then 1 end) dircus
from table1 as u
inner join table2 as tc on u.industry_id=tc.tempcatid 
group by tc.tempcatid, tc.catename
```

Comment: Thanks its provided my expecting result exactly

Comment: @mohan - Great! Please tick next to the answer - you won't be able to do that yet for some more minutes

Comment: Is it better to explicitly state "else NULL", or beter to keep it short but implicit (and so not always understood)?

Comment: @Dems: There's a couple of middle ways, for example: keep it short and explain what it means *or* keep it short and let someone else explain what it means. :)

Comment: Hi again one query i need same before but the count want mcgross column based on 2types of condition 1.ag_code=0  2.ag_code!=0

SELECT tc.catename,
       count(case mcgross when u.ag_code!=0 then 1 end) agnt,
       count(case mcgross when u.ag_code =0 then 1 end) dircus
from table1 as u
inner join table2 as tc on u.industry_id=tc.tempcatid 
group by tc.tempcatid, tc.catename

I need count for mcgross based on the 2 condition 1.ag_code=0   2.ag_code!=0

Answer (score 0):

Hi There you might be able to use the below example to get back the result you require.

```
Select SUM(Inactive) Inactive ,SUM(Active) Active FROM
( 
    Select Count(t1.UserId) Inactive,0 Active 
    FROM
    (select * from users where inactive=1) as t1
    UNION 
    SELECT 0 Inactive,Count(t2.UserId) Active  FROM
    (select * from users where inactive=0) as t2  
) as result
```